# Why do has_many vs has_one relationships cease to if the database object has more than one entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **type model that has_many :products** and a **product model that has_one :type**.

The dynamic methods are working okay, but only if **.product** is called on an object that contains only one instance of **type**.

controller:

```
def index
    @all = Type.all
    @one = Type.find_by_id(2)
end
```

view:

```
<%= debug @one.products %> #=> Hash of products with the type_id of 2
```

So far so good, but then:

```
<%= debug @all.products %>
```

results in a no 'products method defined' error. I think I sort of know why. **@all** contains multiple ids, and rails can't work out that I want all of the **product** entries that contain those multiple foreign keys. It seems it can only manage querying automatically for one foreign key.

Should this be a many to many relationship? That doesn't make sense, because every product really does only have one type. But how can I query for multiple types concisely?

What is want to achieve is have all of the **product** entries on one page, **product** entries that belong to all of the **type** entries.

[image: screen cap of the different data structures]

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Regardless of version though; `@all.products` not working is not a "limitation" of Rails, it's a nonsensical thing for you to ask for. Rails *could* provide this functionality, but doesn't, because it doesn't make semantic sense.

Comment: I understand why I was incuring the error now, but to be honest I don't think it was illogical in the least to assume what I'd assumed

Comment: It doesn't make sense because there is no sane way to implement this such that it fits everybody's needs and expectations. Suppose I have users `a, b, c` in many groups `x, y, z`. The mapping of users to groups is `{a: x}, {b: x, y}, {c: x, y, z}`. What should `User.all.groups` return? A flat array; `[x, x, y, x, y, z]`, or a nested array; `[[x], [x,y], [x, y, z]]` or the unique array; `[x, y, z]`? Or should it just return the list of groups in common to all users, just `x`?

Comment: Fair enough. It's a simply system I'm messing around with. I just saw that A => x and B => y so I assumed AB => xy

Answer (score 1):

`@all = Type.all` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, which does not have a `.products` method.
`@one = Type.find_by_id(2)` returns an actual object, which has `.products`, as you defined it with `has_many :products`.

If you want to have all products from all types, either go `Product.where('type_id = ?', 2')` as Bachan Smruty said, or do (less favored) `@all.collect(&:products)`. In the latter, you'd want to eager-load them by using `Type.includes(:products).all`. But that is - as far as I know - the slowest way since you first reconstitute a group of objects you may not need to collect another group.

Comment: Ah, very obvious why it wasn't working at all now! I tried to find out for myself using the debug. Look at the screen cap in the question, the active record relation (top) and the full blow object (bottom) are pretty much structurally identical.

Comment: Also, Product.where('type_id = ?', '2') (slight error, in your example, missing a speech mark on the 2) only returns Products that have a type_id of 2, not all products. Plain old @all = Product.all seems to be what I want. I just thought there'd be a more elegant why of achieving this. A 'more elegant' way may cause bugs in more complicated databases though, so I'm sure Rails is doing the right thing!

Answer (score 1):

2 points here:

1. Use belongs_to instead of has_one. has_one and belongs_to stands for one-to-one relationship; has_many and belongs_to stands for one-to-many relationship.
2. :products is an instance method for @type, but Type.all is like an Array.